Vuex mutation does not return the latest value of the state
Currently I am working on a functionality where mutation updateConversationBasedOnAssignedUser updates the state current_action.
updateConversationBasedOnAssignedUser uses async/await call using Axios API to determine the value of current_action. Once this mutation is committed, value of  current_action is passed to another mutation to determine what action needs to be taken.
Following is the snapshot of the code :
    const state = { 
        current_action: 'IGNORE',
    }
    
    const actions = {
        async commitAssignedUserChange({ commit }, { id }) {
            await commit('updateConversationBasedOnAssignedUser', id);
            await commit('test');
        }
    }
    
    const mutations = {
      test(state) {
        alert(state.current_action);
      },
      async updateConversationBasedOnAssignedUser(state, id) {
        state.current_action = 'HELLO WORLD';
         await axios
          .get(API_CALL)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            const { success } = data;
            if (success) {
              state.current_action = 'ADD';
            } else {
              state.current_action = 'REMOVE';
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }

Issue that I am facing is the value of the state current_action is set to Hello World
within test mutation even-though I am using mutations synchronously (Eventually settling to correct value). Does async/await have any effects on commits within the action as it seems that  current_action value is returned as soon as the commitAssignedUserChange is triggered.
Is this an anti-pattern as Vuex guidelines states that mutations should be synchronous and in my case I am using Async/Await for synchronous request.

Mutations are mainly meant to update the state and its not recommended to perform async operations inside a mutation.
For performing any async operation you should use action and then update the state using mutation.
You can read more on this here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#on-to-actions

I did go through the documentation as well as planning to refactor the Vuex code completely as last option. However, as per the guidelines I converted asynchronous code to synchronous using Async/Await. Does this have no effect in mutations?

If you want to make async calls, you need to dispatch some actions.
If you want to change the state, you need to commit some mutations.
To access the given state, you can either use the state directly or have a getter, depending if you want the state in itself or some computed values.
This graph explains it well

More context is available here.
Also, consider not mixing async/await and .then please.

If you can, you should also migrate towards VueJS 3 + Pinia btw.

Thank You for pointing out the mixture of async/await & promise syntax. Will refactor that. I did went through the documentation as well as the core concepts within the documentation. I am trying to understand if async/await does not work at all within mutation or are mutations similar to Anonymous callbacks which are set in event queues when we use commit method within action.

@DhavalChheda mutations are purely synchronous as far as I know yes. Hence why you should be doing the async calls first in an action then use the mutation to be able to propagate the state to your components.
